# reformat an object to another object format

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this object schema:

```
{
    car: [
      {
         //Object data
      }
    ],
    motorcycle: [
      {
         //Object data
      }
    ],
    ...
}
```

My question is how I get all the objects from cars and motorcycles in one object like this:

Basically I want all key,value pairs from motorcycle and cars in one object –

```
{
   key1 : {//Object Data},
   key2 : {//Object Data},
}
```

Comment: your expected output is not a valid object syntax. the syntax is key:value. You can have an array of object but not an object containing not naming list of object

Comment: do you mean `{car:{//object data},motorcycle:{object data}}`

Comment: No I changes the question

Comment: Basically I want all key,value pairs from motorcycle and cars in one object

Comment: `car` and `motorcycle` are arrays. Do they contain only one element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Please try this: `const combinedObjects = {...origObj.car, ...origObj.motorcycle};`.

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach using `Object.entries` and `map` and `Object.fromEntries` assuming that there is 1 element in the key array of original object

```js
const a = {
    car: [
      {
       data1: 'data car'
      }
    ],
    motorcycle: [
      {
        data2: 'data cycle'
      }
    ],
}

let x = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(a).map(([key,[val]],index)=> [`key${index+1}`,val]))

console.log(x)
```

If more than 1 objects in key arrays can do something like this

```js
const a = {
    car: [
      {
       data1: 'data car 1'
      },
      {
       data2: 'data car 2'
      }
    ],
    motorcycle: [
      {
        data3: 'data cycle 3'
      }
    ],
}

//Object.entries in case you want access to car,motorcycle....
let x = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(a).flatMap(([key,val])=> val).map((e,index)=>[`key${index+1}`,e] ))

//this should work if no need to access car,motocycle..
// let x = Object.fromEntries(Object.values(a).flatMap((val)=> val).map((e,index)=>[`key${index+1}`,e] ))
 
console.log(x)
```

Comment: @jabaa bit hard to understand without giving a proper example tbh

Comment: @jabaa did a change not sure if thats what OP meant tho